# Navigation.navigate is not a function, navigation is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a problem, in React-Native.

```
<Button title="Save" onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Save' , { image })}/>
    {image && <Image source = {{uri: image}} style= {{flex: 1}}/>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I got an error:

```
navigation.navigate is not a function. (In 'navigation.navigate('Save', {image: image})', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)
```

Comment: Give more context. You probably missed to pass navigation prop to the component where you use Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your component a `navigation` prop like shown below.

Also make sure that it's added in Navigation stack.

```js
function YourComponentName({navigation}){
return (
<View>
<Button title="Save" onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Save' , { image })}/>
    {image && <Image source = {{uri: image}} style= {{flex: 1}}/>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can also use `useNavigation` hooks